# Cannot connect to fedora on port 80

Tags: networking, fedora

I can't access to my local sites on a fedora machine from ubuntu. In firefox I get this error:

> The connection has timed out

In fedora *iptables* I added this line:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Also disabled *selinux*, but still can't connect. Why?

Output of `netstat -tpln`:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 :::139                      :::*                        LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 :::631                      :::*                        LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 :::445                      :::*                        LISTEN      -
```

Output of `iptables -L -n -v`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 9982 1956K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 REJECT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 0 reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
    0     0 REJECT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8 reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  139  9168 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   20 16824 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          state NEW udp dpt:5353
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:631
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:631
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:631
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:137
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:138
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:139
    5   355 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:445
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:80
   87  4524 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 14997 packets, 16M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: On the Fedora host, have you started the httpd server? service httpd start. To make the server start when the system boots, chkconfig httpd on

Comment: Yes. apache server is running and I have no problem on host

Comment: can you please provide the output of `iptables -L -n -v`?

Comment: @UlrichDangel: Please see the edited post

Comment: @NPK the rules look fine, how do you access the host? Via a hostname or IP address? It seems the rule never matched could you maybe try to access your webserver and check if the packet counter of your iptables rule increased?

Comment: If you sun the netstat command with sudo you can see which program is listening, just to make sure it really is your webserver.  Can you connect on the machine itself?  using e.g. w3m?  And can you connect from the client to any other service?  like ssh?  Just to exclude routing issues.  Any errors in the Apache log?

Comment: @UlrichDangel: I tested it with both hostname and IP address. When I try to connect, only the bytes column of the first row increases 1KB

Comment: What happens if you do the tests @Bram suggested? Does it work from localhost? What is the network setup? Do you have multiple nics? Are the devices in different networks?

Comment: Do you have SELinux running on that machine? I know I have fought many times with Fedora, RHEL and Cent due to some weird SELinux rules that are on by default.

Comment: Can you connect locally (using localhost)? Also can you connect from the other machine through any other protocol/port (ping, ssh, telnet, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to open port 80 in the firewall configuration:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=http
```

Answer (score 0):

Netstat ouput shows that you're only accepting connections using IPv6. You must configure your server to also bind to port `80` on address `0.0.0.0`.

Fedora come with a tool that you can use to configure the firewall. Avoid messing with iptables directly.

Comment: That is not necessarily true, it is possible for an AF_INET6 socket to be able to accept IPv4 connections for backwards-compatibility. It would only fail if net.ipv6.bindv6only was set or the socket was openend with the IPV6_V6ONLY option. See: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3493#page-22

Answer (score -1):

Your http server is running over port 80 on IPv6 only. This may be a reason why you can't connect using localhost.

Add "localhost" host name correspond to "::" IP address in "/etc/hosts"

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts
:: localhost
```

Now your firefox shall connect as IPv6 is preferred method of connection if detected.

Alternatively, you can enable your http server listening over both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Cedric's comment on the similar answer above seems to be applicable here:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39216/cannot-connect-to-fedora-on-port-80/404808#comment62569_41380